# C# ASP.net MVC Ajax MySQL DATATABLES Column searching can't pass search value to Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

**Trying to Achieve**

Using Datatable, I am trying to implement column searching. I wish to pass `search[value]` and `column index` to `Controller` where I have a `filter method` that will filter and load the list.

[image: Table]

**What I have tried**

With the following code, I bind `keyup change` to each column. During `keyup change`, I managed to get `valueData` and `column index` from the table

```
    table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {

        $('input', $('.filters td')[colIdx]).bind('keyup change', function () {
            var searchColIndex = $(this).parent().index();
            //=== During keyup or change, it will go through each column
            var columnIndex = colIdx;

            //=== When the searchCol matches the columnIndex
            if (searchColIndex == columnIndex) {
                //=== Ideally will call Draw and pass the value to Controller
                var valuedata = $(this).val();
                //table.column(0).search($(this).val()).draw();
                table
                 .column(colIdx)
                 .search(valuedata)
                 .draw();
            }

        });
    });
```

[image: KeyUpTriggerAndGetValue]

**`Controllers` could not manage to get the `search value` or `column index`**

[image: Controllers]

**But if I search at the top right hand corner search box, `Controllers` able to request the value**

[image: TopRightSearchWillGetValues]

**Code**
https://github.com/BROMVC5/BROSTANDARD.git

**Suggested by Murat**

```
    var table = $('#tablePassword').DataTable({

        "paging": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "processing": true, // control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, // recommended to use serverSide when data is more than 10000 rows for performance reasons
        "info": true,   // control table information display field
        "lengthChange": true,
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 20, 50, -1], [5, 20, 50, "All"]],    // use the first inner array as the page length values and the second inner array as the displayed options
        "colReorder": true,
        "orderMulti": true, // for disable multiple column at once

        "language": {
            searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
        },

        "order": [["3", "desc"]], //=== Not working during stateSave

        //"ajax":{
        //    "url": "/Password/AjaxGetJsonData",
        //    "type": "POST"
        //},
        "AjaxSource": "/Password/AjaxGetJsonData",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "all", "value": true });
            $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                fnCallback(json)
            });
        },

        //*** Added the following code ****
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "width": "5%", "targets": 'NumCol', "data": "id",
                "orderable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                }
            },
            {
                "targets": 'LoginCol', 
                "data": "LoginID", "orderable": true
            },
            {
                "targets": 'NameCol', 
                "data": "Name", "orderable": true
            },
            {
                "targets": 'DtCreatedCol', 
                "data": "DateCreated", "orderable": true
            },
            {
                "targets": 'EditCol', // The third column
                "className": "text-center",
                "orderable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="/Password/PasswordDet/' + full.AutoINC + '"><img src="../../Content/myPics/edit-2-24.png" ></a>';
                }
            }
        ],

   });


   $('body').on('click', '#btnGet', function () {

        //to get currently clicked row object
        var row = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

        //to get currently clicked row data
        var rowData = table.row(row).data();

        //to get currently clicked row id (first column value (at index [0])
        var rowId = rowData[0];

        var row = $(this).closest("tr"),            // Finds the closest row <tr>
        rowId = row.find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
    });
```

**Suggested by Murat Controller is not called and hang**

[image: ControllersNotCalled]

Comment: are you getting any data in the `Request.QueryString`? and what `HttpVerb` are you using on `AjaxGetJsonData` `Get` or `Post`?

Comment: Just use Request["search[value]"]. I think that would work.

Comment: @UxmaanAli not working using  Request["search[value]"].

Comment: @vikscool I am using `Get` I have posted the Ajax code and additional stuff.

Comment: The reason why you are getting `blank/empty` string for `search[value]` is you have enabled `"filter": true` which enabled a search box on the top right corner of your table. And you are trying to call the search from the individual search boxes for each column but the value that you are reading is from the main Search box. So, change the read logic to be something like: `columns[index][search][value]` to make the search work.

Comment: @vikscool sorry I am a noob how would the syntax like for columns[index][search][value]

Comment: use `Request.QueryString["columns[indexOfColumnToSearch]search[value]"]` or if you are not certain of what column is calling it, change your `JS` code to pass the col-index along with the value to search with a fixed column like:`table.column(0).search(colIdx+'|'+this.value).draw();` and then in you server-side code split the value from `var searchParam = Request.QueryString["columns[0]search[value]"]split('|');` Here `[0]` is the col-index and `[1]` is your searched value.

Comment: @vikscool Sorry, I have tried everything you suggested but still can't pass the `search value and column index` during `draw` to the `Controller`? Setting filter: false, the search still take value from the top right-hand corner.

Comment: Did you check these are sent with the ajax ? If there are parameters then try to change type from get to post.

Comment: @UxmaanAli Yes it is sent by Ajax, tried `post` but still the same not pick up by the `Controllers` I suspect is the `Request.QueryString syntax` or somehow should I name the `input field` an ID and called it?

Comment: If it is Asp.Net Core then var search = Request.Form["search[value]"] would work. If it is in Asp.Net then var search = Request["search[value]"] works.

Comment: @HanzCheah sorry for the delayed response try to using `Post` request instead of `Get` and use `Request.Form` instead of `Reqeust.QueryString` also have a look at [Implement Jquery Datatable in Asp.Net MVC Blog post](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/11/implement-jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-mvc.html) for implementation(*3rd Section*).

Comment: @vikscool ok thanks will look into it and come back on it

Comment: @vikscool I have updated my questions with more elaborated gif and what the code is not doing. I have tried your suggestions of `Request.Form` and `Request.QueryString` but still not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function () {
    table = $('#tablePassword).DataTable();
});

$('body').on('click', '#btnGet', function () {
    
    //to get currently clicked row object
    var row = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
 
    //to get currently clicked row data
    var rowData = table.row(row).data();
 
    //to get currently clicked row id (first column value (at index [0])
    var rowId = rowData[0];
});
```

In order to post extra parameters in jQuery DataTables, use fnServerData method besides ajaxSource as shown below (do not forget to use the same parameter names on the Controller method):

```
// code omitted for brevity

"serverSide": true,
"ajaxSource": "/Password/AjaxGetJsonData", 
 
//fnServerData used to inject the parameters into the AJAX call sent to the server-side
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    aoData.push({ "name": "all", "value": true });
    $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
        fnCallback(json)
    });
},
```

***Update:***
Please do not forget **to use the same parameter names** on the Controller method. You can also use the following approach in order to get row values from DataTable:

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr"),            // Finds the closest row <tr>
rowId = row.find("td:nth-child(1)").text(); // Finds the 1st <td> element (Id)
```

Here is the Controller and Model parts for this solution:

***Controller:***

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns data by the criterion
/// </summary>
/// <param name="param">Request sent by DataTables plugin</param>
/// <returns>JSON text used to display data
/// <list type="">
/// <item>sEcho - same value as in the input parameter</item>
/// <item>iTotalRecords - Total number of unfiltered data. This value is used in the message: 
/// "Showing *start* to *end* of *iTotalDisplayRecords* entries (filtered from *iTotalDisplayRecords* total entries)
/// </item>
/// <item>iTotalDisplayRecords - Total number of filtered data. This value is used in the message: 
/// "Showing *start* to *end* of *iTotalDisplayRecords* entries (filtered from *iTotalDisplayRecords* total entries)
/// </item>
/// <item>aoData - Twodimensional array of values that will be displayed in table. 
/// Number of columns must match the number of columns in table and number of rows is equal to the number of records that should be displayed in the table</item>
/// </list>
/// </returns>
[Authorize(Roles = "CanViewLab")]
public ActionResult GetLabs(JQueryDataTableParamModel param, bool isAll)
{          
    var allRecords = repository.Labs; //All records
    if (!isAll)
    {
        allRecords = allRecords.Where(m => m.StatusId == Status.Active); //Only active records
    };
    IEnumerable<Lab> filteredRecords;

    //Check whether the users should be filtered by keyword
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
    {
        //Used if particulare columns are filtered 
        var nameFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_1"]);
        var placeFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_2"]);

        //Optionally check whether the columns are searchable at all 
        var isNameSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_1"]);
        var isPlaceSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_2"]);

        //filteredRecords = repository.Labs
        filteredRecords = allRecords //For including "isAll" parameter to the "filteredRecords" as "allRecords" parameter
                .Where(c => isNameSearchable && c.Name.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                            ||
                            isPlaceSearchable && c.Place.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()));
    }
    else
    {
        filteredRecords = allRecords;
    }

    //!!! The number of request variables (bSortable_X) is equal to the iColumns variable.
    var isNameSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_1"]);
    var isCodeSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_2"]);
    var isStatusNameSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_3"]);
    var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);

    Func<Lab, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 && isNameSortable ? c.Name :
                                                    sortColumnIndex == 2 && isCodeSortable ? c.Place :
                                                    sortColumnIndex == 3 && isStatusNameSortable ? c.StatusName :
                                                "");

    var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"]; // asc or desc
    if (sortDirection == "asc")
        filteredRecords = filteredRecords.OrderBy(orderingFunction);
    else
        filteredRecords = filteredRecords.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);

    var displayedRecords = filteredRecords.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
    var result = from c in displayedRecords select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.Id), c.Name, c.Place, c.StatusName };
    return Json(new
    {
        sEcho = param.sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = allRecords.Count(),
        iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredRecords.Count(),
        aaData = result
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

***Model:***

```
/// <summary>
/// Class that encapsulates most common parameters sent by DataTables plugin
/// </summary>
public class JQueryDataTableParamModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Request sequence number sent by DataTable, same value must be returned in response
    /// </summary>       
    public string sEcho{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Text used for filtering
    /// </summary>
    public string sSearch{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of records that should be shown in table
    /// </summary>
    public int iDisplayLength{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// First record that should be shown(used for paging)
    /// </summary>
    public int iDisplayStart{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of columns in table
    /// </summary>
    public int iColumns{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of columns that are used in sorting
    /// </summary>
    public int iSortingCols{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Comma separated list of column names
    /// </summary>
    public string sColumns{ get; set; }
}
```

And here is how I retrieve and list the data:

***View:***

```
<div class="portlet-body form">
    <div class="form-body">
        <table id="dtbLab" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Id </th>
                    <th> Name </th>                             
                    <th> Place </th>
                    <th> Status </th>
                    <!-- (!!! "columnDefs" width SHOULD BE set up in <th> section of column header) -->
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
        
<script>
var table;
$(document).ready(function () {
    table = $('#dtbLab')
        .DataTable({                
            tableTools: {
            "sRowSelect": "single",
            "aButtons": []
            },
            buttons: [],
        "autoWidth": false,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajaxSource": "/Lab/GetLabs",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "isAll", "value": isAllChecked }); // Add some extra data to the sender
            $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                /* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables */
                fnCallback(json);
            });
        },
        "processing": false, //Enable or disable the display of a 'processing' indicator when the table is being processed (e.g. a sort)
        "columns": [
                        {
                            "name": "Id",
                            "width": '5%', /* '5px' */
                            "searchable": false,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                                return '<a href=\"Controller/Action/' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                            }
                        },
                        { "name": "Name", "width": '45%' },
                        { "name": "Code", "width": '45%' },
                        { "name": "Status", "width": '10%' }
        ]       

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yildiz, thanks for your suggested answer but I think it is not what I want. I can't seem to load my `list` when I use `fnServerData` Moreover, how do I pass `column index` and their respective `search[value]`? Please elaborate if you can

Comment: I tried your code, but can you elaborate more about the `Controllers` When initial loading the page with `fnServerData` I am unable to load my `list` into the `Datatables

Comment: Yildiz, how do you get the data into the list item?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help but I actually haven't found a solution. The problem is when  I follow your suggestions. The page will not load as stated above. If you go to **GitHub** and follow my code. I am using a `CreateData` method which I will call a `MySQL query` and populate into `List<DataItem>` For your example, I am not sure how you populate the DB. By the way when changing to POST, the original `Search at the left hand corner` and `Sort by 1 column` won't work. Your help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Does the request hits to the Controller method when you debug your code? If so where it ends and what is the error? On the other hand I think you comment out [Authorize(Roles = "")] line that may cause the problem.

Comment: Nope, it always only get the value from the `top left search box` No matter what I tried? My code is at [link](https://github.com/BROMVC5/BROSTANDARD) if you have time to play around with it. Sorry I have just started to get around MVC use to work with Classic ASP.

Comment: It is also better to have a look at the Concole and Network in Chrome Debugger Console and examine the response message.

Comment: I am using the `sSQL query string` to called a mySQL database.